# Creating a session with Ruby/RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I recently received some API documentation from a company that I wanted to pull some data from.  They told me that I need to create a session first, which will return my session_id.  I have no idea what they mean by this?  I tried the googles and got some stuff on RoR that talked about sessions but it sort of went over my head as I haven't done any work with rails before.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#accessing-the-session

Can anybody give me some direction here?

Comment: With respect to your frustration, this question is a little too broad for this site. The topic of sessions in Rails is a wide one and would be difficult to address in this format.

Comment: I think we might need to see some of the API documentation.  "session" here might mean a session _with the other server's API_, not a session in your rails server.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds more like you need to create a *session* with the API endpoint you're trying to access and not in your Rails application. If that is the case think of *session_id* as a token you'll need to pass along with any other API requests that you make. If you include information on the API you're trying to access we can help more(that is if it is a public API you're trying to access)!

Comment: That is definitely what I am trying to do, unfortunately I cannot give out the information as I had to register for it and got my own devID and authKey :(

Basically the url structure is:
http://api_stuff_for_the_site/devID/authKey

I tried to do GETs, POSTs / get_response and with the url structure above and had no luck.

Comment: @DJ DeStefano, great. In the documentation the should be able to point you in the direction of the API call you need to make to get the *session_id* and how to pass it along with any API calls after that.

Comment: yeah so the final form is:

http:// api_stuff_for_the_site/create_sesssion_method/devID/authKey

Now what do I do with that?

Comment: You make a get/post to that url, you'll get a session_id in some format(within json, xml, etc) in the response, and you'll use that id in your next requests to the API for data(directly in the url, as a header, etc). That's in general terms, you'll need to work with the documentation/company supplying the API for specifics since you can't share here. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok yeah that is what I have been trying to do and the response I get back does not contain the session_id unfortunately.  I will contact them for the specifics.